# DataContractSerializer: preserve string member that happens to be raw xml?

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm a little inexperienced with the DataContract paradigm, and I'm running into a deserialization problem. I have a field that's a string, but it contains xml and it's not being deserialized correctly. I have a feeling that it's because the DCS is treating it as input to the serializer and not as an opaque string object.

Is there some way to mark a DataMember in code to say "This thing is a string, don't treat its contents as xml" similar to XmlIgnore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the easiest way to do this was just to cast the xml field coming from sql server to a varchar(max) when retrieving it from the database.

```
 CAST(CONVERT(XML,[RawXml],0) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS RawXml
```

In this case, the serializer seems to be ignoring it as desired.
Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the equivalent to `[XmlIgnore]` is just **not putting** a `[DataMember]` on your property/field - if you're decorating everything with `[DataMember]` otherwise.

But I don't see how you could tell the DataContractSerializer to treat the property as an opaque string and nothing else.

You could try to have a separate property which adds `<![CDATA[` before and `]]>` after your content string, and serialize that property instead of your raw XML property (by decorating that new property with the `[DataMember]` attribute).

Something like this:

```
 public string XmlContent { get; set; }

 [DataMember]
 public string XmlContentSafe 
 { 
    get { return "<![CDATA[" + XmlContent + "]]>"; }
 }
```

Maybe that way you can trick the DCS ? (never tried it myself - just guessing....)

Comment: Yeah, I guess XmlIgnore isn't quite what I would be going for since I want the field to be transmitted, just not serialized. I guess I was hoping for a trick with DataMember to indicate you wanted a member to be serialized to a certain type. I'll give the CData thing a try though!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do, just declare the property with raw XML as XmlElement

```
[DataMember]
public XmlElement RawXML { private get; set; }
```